# undefined local variable or method `count_notification' for #Spec::Runner::TeamcityFormatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubymine

Upgraded to latest rubymine 6.3 and while trying to run all the specs using spec configuration coming across the issue. Looking at the logs looks like a rubymine issue. Any idea how to fix this issue?

> `` /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/rspec3_formatter.rb:250:in `dump_summary': undefined local variable or method `count_notification' for #<Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter:0x007f8d338fd3e8> (NameError)
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:134:in `block in notify'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:133:in `each'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:133:in `notify'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:116:in `finish'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:55:in `ensure in report'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:55:in `report'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:107:in `run_specs'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
>       from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
>       from /Users/ac027466/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
>   /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby -I/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib:/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-support-3.1.2/lib /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb failed ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to rubymine 6.3.3 fixed the issue for me.